# Problem with labeling equations in fleqn environment

Tags: equations, numbering, labels

I have trouble for labeling my equation in `fleqn`. Even though I do include `\label{...}`, it refuses do show the number corresponding. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
            \[ 
                \begin{pmatrix}
                    \cos(\alpha) & 0 & -\sin(\alpha)\\
                    0 & 1 & 0\\ 
                    \sin(\alpha) & 0 & \cos(\alpha)
                \end{pmatrix}
                ^{-1}
                =
                \begin{pmatrix}
                    \cos(\alpha) & 0 & \sin(\alpha)\\
                    0 & 1 & 0\\ 
                    -\sin(\alpha) & 0 & \cos(\alpha)
                \end{pmatrix}
                \label{eq:inverse}
            \]
        \end{fleqn}

\end {document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you have displaymath-mode inside displaymath-mode, start by removint the lines containing `\[` and `\]`

Comment: And for one-liners, you probably should not use `fleqn`

Comment: For `fleqn`, that is the only way that I found to make the matrices align on the left side. Without `\[` and `\]`, the code didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\[…\]` is a `displaymath` (or `equation*`) environment, that does not show an equation number. You need environments like `equation`, `align` etc. to get an equation number. See the [`amsmath` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf) and the [`mathtools` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf) for more information about those environments.

You can use `mathtools` with option `fleqn`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
                \begin{pmatrix}
                    \cos(\alpha) & 0 & -\sin(\alpha)\\
                    0 & 1 & 0\\ 
                    \sin(\alpha) & 0 & \cos(\alpha)
                \end{pmatrix}
                ^{-1}
                &=
                \begin{pmatrix}
                    \cos(\alpha) & 0 & \sin(\alpha)\\
                    0 & 1 & 0\\ 
                    -\sin(\alpha) & 0 & \cos(\alpha)
                \end{pmatrix}
                \label{eq:inverse}
\end{align}

\end {document}
```

[image]

or the `flalign` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
               \begin{pmatrix}
                    \cos(\alpha) & 0 & -\sin(\alpha)\\
                    0 & 1 & 0\\ 
                    \sin(\alpha) & 0 & \cos(\alpha)
                \end{pmatrix}
                ^{-1}
                & =
                \begin{pmatrix}
                    \cos(\alpha) & 0 & \sin(\alpha)\\
                    0 & 1 & 0\\ 
                    -\sin(\alpha) & 0 & \cos(\alpha)
                \end{pmatrix}
                \label{eq:inverse} &&
\end{flalign}

\end {document}
```

[image]

Comment: any `align` structure shouldn't really be used for a single-line display.  the spacing in relation to the text above and below won't be quite correct, or at least not consistent with the space above and below multi-line displays.