# How can I keep equations left-aligned only if they do not exceed a certain width?

Tags: math-mode, equations, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, alignment

I would like all my equations to be left aligned by default, and to become centered as soon as `2*fleqn_indent + eq_width >= textwidth`.

The following MWE might be more explicative:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\noindent this should stay left-aligned
\[
  a + b = c
\]
this should be centered like the one after it
\[
  \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 +
  + 13 + 14 + 15 + \dots
\]
{
  \makeatletter
  \setbool{@fleqn}{false}
  \makeatother
  \[
    \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12
    + + 13 + 14 + 15 + \dots
  \]
}
and the same for all other math environments, for example \texttt{align}:
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i &= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 +
                             + 13 + 14 + 15 + 16 + \dots \\
                          &= -\frac{1}{12}
\end{align*}
{
  \makeatletter
  \setbool{@fleqn}{false}
  \makeatother
  \begin{align*}
    \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i &= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12
                               + 13 + 14 + 15 + 16 + \dots \\
                            &= -\frac{1}{12}
  \end{align*}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can't (using standard `amsmath`) change the value of the fleqn boolean mid document, you can change its value but the effects are unexpected, the package uses the option at package loading time and only fully defines the selected variants, so in some simple cases changing the boolean accidentally appears to work,but mostly it doesn't.

Comment: then what is the correct way to disable `fleqn` locally?

Comment: it is not a supported feature. There is a package (I forget the name) that offers local flush left if you use centered by default, I'll see if I can find it. Bernard mentions it a few times on this site.  Is switching to centred really useful? In almost all cases if it doesn't fit then it will still not fit centred in which case you will need to break the line, in whic case you can go back to flush left. so it is only a few equations right at teh edge case where it makes a difference

Comment: nccmath fleqn env, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369240/problem-with-labeling-equations-in-fleqn-environment

Comment: I use flush left by default so that package would be to little use to me. Like you already said, this isn't for really long equations. It's for those equations that still fit in one line but are long enough that it doesn't look good to keep them flushed left.

Comment: I'd just add a negative space at the start of the formula (by say half the indent) for those cases.

Comment: But I'd need to 1) eyeball it, 2) do it manually every time, 3) make sure to remove those negative spaces if I switch to a layout with a larger textwidth. It'd be nice to redefine `equation`, `align` etc.. to have that behaviour built into them.

Comment: equation might be possible, align would be pretty hard as technically it is always full width

Comment: it's not that your request is completely unreasonable, but it just isn't supported. Finding the natural width of an alignment is not entirely trivial, but if you did that keeping it flush left but reducing the indent would be easier than switching to centred as the centering code is not loaded (mostly because of the memory constraints of the machines in 1993.....)

Comment: as long as the output is the same I don't think it matters if logically the equation becomes centered or if it stays left aligned with a smaller indent

Comment: \flalign supports both left and center alignments (by adding empty fields), but you will have to decide which to use ahead of time.

Comment: Should it still use the \mathindent space when there is an equation number? Should it be centered when wider than the column width?

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Yes, `\mathindent` is usually wider than the equation number so that should be ok. Yes, as soon as the equation width passes the threshold (this is certainly the case if the equation doesn't even fit in one `\textwidth`, let alone `\textwidth -2\mathindent`) it should behave like a centered one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solution works.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{datetime2}

% macro to get the length of equation
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59925/how-to-get-width-of-equation
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\settowidthofalign}[2]{%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{
    \begin{align*}
    #2
    \ifmeasuring@\else\global\let\got@maxcolwd\maxcolumn@widths\fi
    \end{align*}
  }%
  \begingroup
  \def\or{+}\edef\x{\endgroup\global#1=\dimexpr\got@maxcolwd\relax}\x
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

% stores the width of equation
\dim_new:N \g__eqn_width

% the threshold between left equation-aligned and centered equation
\dim_new:N \g_eqn_align_threshold_dim
\dim_gset:Nn \g_eqn_align_threshold_dim {0.6\linewidth}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{smartalign*}{+b}{}{
    \settowidthofalign{\g__eqn_width}{#1}
    \dim_compare:nNnTF {\g__eqn_width} < {\g_eqn_align_threshold_dim} {
        \begin{fleqn}[2em]
            \begin{align*}
                #1
            \end{align*}
        \end{fleqn}
    } {
        \begin{align*}
            #1
        \end{align*}
    }
}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{smartalign}{+b}{}{
    \settowidthofalign{\g__eqn_width}{#1}
    \dim_compare:nNnTF {\g__eqn_width} < {\g_eqn_align_threshold_dim} {
        \begin{fleqn}[2em]
            \begin{align}
                #1
            \end{align}
        \end{fleqn}
    } {
        \begin{align}
            #1
        \end{align}
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\noindent Example 1: 
\begin{smartalign*}
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + \dots
\end{smartalign*}

\noindent Example 2:
\begin{smartalign*}
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + \dots
\end{smartalign*}

\noindent Example 3:
\begin{smartalign*}
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i &= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12
                               + 13  + \dots \\
                            &= -\frac{1}{12}
\end{smartalign*}

\noindent Example 4:
\begin{smartalign}
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i &= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + \dots \\
                            &= -\frac{1}{12}
\end{smartalign}

\noindent Example 5:
\begin{smartalign}
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i &= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + \dots \\
                            &= -\frac{1}{12}
\end{smartalign}


\end{document}
```

Comment: it clearly doesn't.

Comment: @noibe I am not sure what you want. It aligns left when equation width is less than a threshold.

Comment: the stuff inside `fleqn` isn't indented. Compare the output of your code to the one I posted.

Comment: @noibe You can set the margin of `fleqn` by adding an optional argument. See the updated version.

Comment: would it be possible to extend this to math environments other than `align`, for example `equation`?